# Calling base Text method on custom TextBox

Tags: inheritance

I'm trying to create a CurrencyTextBox that inherits from TextBox.  I'm seeing some really weird behavior that I just don't understand.

After lots of testing, I think I can summarize as follows:

In the class code, when I access base.Text (to get the textbox's text), I'm actually getting the return value of my overridden Text property.

I thought the base keyword would ensure that the underlying object's methods get called.

To demonstrate:

```
public class cTestTextBox : System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    {
        string strText = "";

        public cTestTextBox()
        {
            SetVal("AAA");
            base.Text = "TEST";
        }
        public override string Text
        {
            get
            {
                string s = strText;
                s = "++" + s + "++";
                return s;
            }
        }
        public void SetVal(string val)
        {
            strText = val;
        }
    }
```

Place this control on a form and set a breakpoint on the constructor. Run the app. Hover your mouse over the base.Text expression. Note that the tooltip shows you the value of the overridden property, not the base property. Execute the SetVal() statement and again hover your mouse over the base.Text expression. Note that the tooltop shows you the value of the overridden property, not the base property.

How do I reliably access the Text property of the textbox from which I'm inheriting?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. Not sure what happened to the 'deleted' post but he might have been on the right track. To see if some base-class is calling your .Text, put something in .Text that causes an infinite loop if that's what is happening:

```
public override string Text
{
    get
    {
         return base.Text; 
    }
}
```